# Read XML data and write to new file with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I may be over thinking this but are there any extra steps I am missing after reading my XML data into a string and before writing it to a local file?

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');

//MY URL TO A XML PAGE STYLED WITH XML STYLE SHEET
$url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/somexmlfile.xml";

//SAVE CONTENTS OF PAGE IN XML_DATA
$xml_data = file_get_contents($url);


//REMOVE STYLE SHEET INFO
$search2 = '<?xml-stylesheet href="latest_ob.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>';
$xml_data = str_replace( $search2, "", $xml_data);


//WRITE MY DATA TO A BACKUP FILE AND THEN ECHO TO THE SCREEN FOR A FLASH APP CALLING THE INFO

        $myFile = "data_backup.xml";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = $xml_data;
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);

        echo $xml_data;
```

The reason I ask this is when I try opening my backup XML file in Dreamweaver it crashes everytime. I was thinking there could be an encoding issue possible.

Comment: Can you open the backup XML file in another application, like XMLSpy or Notepad++?

Comment: Yes if I open it in reg notepad it opens but the structure is no longer there.

Comment: have you tried commenting out the `str_replace` line? that way you could see if it's an encoding issue or Dreamweaver has a problem with the missing stylesheet info.

Comment: To be honest I'm mystified as to why you'd be retrieving, loading, processing and saving XML data as a string. If you read the file into an XML object to process and save you would at least have some debug points and the possibility of raising errors regarding XML structure.

Comment: @James I don't have to save it as a string.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the output of the saved file here we could see what the problem was? But if you're working with XML then you may as well use the right tools - load it into one of the php xml objects.

Comment: Let me try that first James +1  and then I will post my saved file output.